# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: in HTTP Get on Android

Tags: java, android, http

I'm executing a HTTP Get from an Async function and I keep getting this UnsatisfiedLinkError:-

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[DexPathList[[
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-universal-image-loader-1.9.5_5a96e3a3bb879858d826e5f3576c34ad5d6c1936-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.3.0_55d9fdcf7c91c0058d2cbcc7e08fd782b38fe66d-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-socialauth-android-3.2_9611dca6f615df1d34c2b5a60ba28a7611388175-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-socialauth-4.4_1b9c6d31199994c03c332e5e0578e2f0b2fe0c48-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-simple-xml-2.7.1_f2a506737e8b5ed93d4b881fc0c6c7a35026d813-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-library-2.4.0_16c20551d1515298e4f820dbb2437cde217a49b7-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.1-jar-with-dependencies_a1a9b67170b6d055b09be56a35ddecd8b9faafce-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.3.0_e42bbcf06b9ce4060096cb8ce36b6ab3c865197c-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-httpclient-4.3.6_e4c2a7ccc6f36fc0c0b6db3cd84168431f19da97-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-guava-19.0_789e0cb8a020dcf43fb5056f93875e715c03d36c-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-gcm_4bcd93ef73ae7672956b56c7a5314a899b41e0a9-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-de.mrmaffen-vlc-android-sdk-1.9.8_183f7022a4ff9bc2fcad3ecf80fe616b030d8981-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.github.ganfra-material-spinner-1.1.1_3c6f77a530740d43591c90873c9d9105e0afdcd9-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-23.3.0_a59a3afa176f79a2a84e41a6156deee0023dc2e8-classes.dex",
dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.3.0_95f566be28123c8c85ef97806b7b803eab311dd5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.myapp.myapp/f
```

The code I'm executing is simply as below (inside doInBackground) :-

```
 String url1 = "http://172.23.3.54:8054/Streaming/channels/102/preview";

 httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 httpParams = httpclient.getParams();
 httpget = new HttpGet(URI.create(url1));
 HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5 * 1000);
 HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 5 * 1000);
 Log.i(TAG, "1. Sending http request");

 credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "12345");
 httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);


 try {
  res = httpclient.execute(httpget);
  Log.i(TAG, "2. Request finished, status = " + res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + ", " + res.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());

  try {
   InputStream is = res.getEntity().getContent(); //error occurs here
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

I can't seem to find much info about `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. I've tried rebuilding the project but to no avail. Would appreciate if someone can tell me the possible cause of this as the stack trace didn't provide much useful information.

---

### Update

The error occurs only on my actual device (LG G4) and not on Nexus 4 AVD. It looks something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally managed to solve this problem. First, I disabled instant run on Android studio. This somehow changed the error message that was produced:-

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.myapp-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.myapp.myapp-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libImageProc.so"
```

So it turns out that native libraries was missing.

In the end, I solved the problem by applying a filter in my gradle build.

```
defaultConfig {
...
    ndk {
        moduleName "ImageProc"
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
    }
}
```

What this does is specify only 32-bit architectures to be packaged.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of HttpDefaultClient() to HttpUrlConnection You have to use because onw     it's depricated. or if you use HttpDefaultClient() then you need to add library for HttpDefaultClient so i suggest you to use HttpUrlConnection.

```
private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView.setText(result);
   }
}


private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
InputStream is = null;
// Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
// web page content.
int len = 500;

try {
    URL url = new URL(myurl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Starts the query
    conn.connect();
    int response = conn.getResponseCode();
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
    is = conn.getInputStream();

    // Convert the InputStream into a string
    String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
    return contentAsString;

// Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
// finished using it.
} finally {
    if (is != null) {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

}

> Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.

```
public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
Reader reader = null;
reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
char[] buffer = new char[len];
reader.read(buffer);
return new String(buffer);
```

}

> It may help you.

Comment: In fact, I have tried HTTPUrlConnection, and proceeded to try HttpDefaultClient instead. The same error occurs.
One weird thing is, it happens only on my actual device. I can run the code without errors in my Nexus 4 AVD